# How else can I express the concept of ' just to be on the safe side'

Tags: expression-choice

I always use this expression when I want to say that I just want to be prudent about something. Are there other ways to convey the same concept, other idioms or expressions I can use alternatively?

Comment: Is using "just want to be prudent" unacceptable for some reason?

Comment: . . . or "prudence demands that we . . ." (assuming no one in your office is named Prudence).

Comment: It is fine of course,but  my question is, if I may: are there other expressions or idioms I am not aware of?

Comment: "Just in case," perhaps? But just how are we supposed to know which phrases you are and are not aware of?

Comment: @BrianDonovan, as I said in the question 'just to be on the safe side' is the only that I know and use. Any other expression or idiom, like the one you mentioned above, is most welcome.

Comment: "Just to be safe" or "Just in case" are more concise ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: Not an established idiom (except perhaps in my own family): _Better to have it and not need it than need it and not have it._ It won't work for everything, but it works in some cases, such as, "Should we bring a raincoat?" or, "Should I back up the data on this hard drive?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*[Play (it) safe](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+safe)*
to be careful and not take risks

*[hedge](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hedge)*
(against something): to lessen the risk of something happening
*hedge* (your bets): to protect yourself against making the wrong choice

[*Abundant caution*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aList_of_Latin_phrases_%28A%E2%80%93E%29)
*Abundans cautela non nocet* (Lt.) – "Abundant caution does no harm." Thus, one can never be too careful; even excessive precautions don't hurt anyone.

Comment: I like the Latin adage. Advice always sounds more prudent in Latin.

Comment: +1 Also *in an excess of caution*, often said self-depricatingly/disingenuously about ones own conduct.

Comment: @TheodoreBroda Dictum semper quidem prudentiores Latine!

Answer (score 19):

"Err on the side of caution" comes to mind.

Comment: First to my mind as well

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the other answers, "Better safe than sorry" also comes to mind.

Answer (score 3):

"*A stitch in time saves nine*" they say. So, *for peace of mind*, I lock my doors at night.

Comment: Not sure I'd agree on the similarity with "A stitch in time saves nine," @MajorMalfunction, because that adage applies when damage has already occurred.

Answer (score 3):

There is a famous "Yogi Berra quote" that "you don't want to make the wrong mistake."

Answer (score 2):

"And, as braces (suspenders in the US) to go with my belt..."

It's a bit self-deprecating, but if it's something you're consciously using to mix up the vocabulary a bit, other people have probably noticed as well, and poking a bit of fun at yourself from time to time is healthy for all concerned.

Answer (score 2):

"Conservatively", or "Just to be conservative"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, I think the following idiom may prove useful:

[Don't bite off more than you can chew](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bite+off+more+than+can+chew), suggesting a prudent and measured behaviour.

> If you bite off more than you can chew, you take on more responsibilities than you can manage. 'Don't bite off more than you can chew' is often used to advise people against agreeing to more than they can handle.

Comment: This may be too specific for the OP's needs.

Comment: This phrase relates a caution about being too ambitious, rather than addressing the question's point, which is about concern for contingencies.

Answer (score 1):

"Conservatively" is a word that came to my mind when I read this. E.g.

> This will take no less than one month to complete, to be on the safe side.

vs

> This will take no less than one month to complete, **conservatively** estimating.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a colloquialism but "I may be wearing shark armor in the shallow end but, ...." is not unheard of in Seattle. Though, I've only heard it used to describe when someone's being overly-cautious: "you don't need shark chain-mail to go in a swimming pool".

Comment: You could tweak this expression to suit the OP's purposes; something like: _sometimes it's good to wear shark armor – [even in the shallow end](http://i629.photobucket.com/albums/uu16/jazmac_2009/shark_in_pool2.jpg)_.

Answer (score 0):

[Play one's cards close to one's chest](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+cards+close+to+chest)

> Fig. to keep to oneself or be very cautious in one's dealing with
>   people. (As if one were playing cards and not permitting anyone to see
>   any of the cards.) *He is very cautious. He plays his cards close to
>   his chest.*

AmEng [Play (keep) one's cards close to one's vest](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/play-or-keep-one%27s-cards-close-to-one%27s-chest-or-north-american-vest)

> *Who supports the program, who wants to phase it out, and who's keeping their cards close to their vest, trying to figure which way the wind will blow?*